# Telerik mvc grid with Edit mode true or false

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid, telerik

Which approach would be good to manage whether the grid should be .Editable. Where can i control if .Editable should be true or false based on something that happens server side?

I want to do this because i don´t want to be able to edit a grid if i have a field in for example DB that tells me that "editdata = false" and therefor i cannot alter this data in the grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to set a ViewBag.GridEditMode or something like that in your controller.

So, for example if the grid needs to be editable, in your controller;

```
ViewBag.GridEditMode = true;
```

Then, in your view set the grid Mode like,

```
.Editable((bool)ViewBag.GridEditMode)
```

Hope this helps.